# Fetch values of aggregated columns in Propel

Tags: symfony1, propel, symfony-1.4

I am trying to make following query in Propel:

```
$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->clearSelectColumns();
$criteria->addSelectColumn(TableName::COLUMN1)
    ->addSelectColumn(TableName::COLUMN2)
    ->addAsColumn('alias1', 'DATE('.TableName::INIT_TIME.')')
    ->addAsColumn('alias2', 'COUNT('.TableName::DOWNLOAD_START_TIME.')')
    ->addGroupByColumn('DATE('.TableName::INIT_TIME.')')
    ->addGroupByColumn(TableName::DOWNLOAD_START_TIME);

$logs = TableName::doSelect($criteria);
```

It seems that everything OK and according to MySQL log file query generated and saved to server right. However I cannot get values of aggregated columns.

doSelect returns array of TableName objects which have no methods to fetch aggregated columns. So, how can I do it?

PS: I am talking about symfony 1.4 with Propel if it matters.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid the use of `Criteria`, use the `ModelCriteria` API instead (documentation available at: http://www.propelorm.org/reference/model-criteria.html)

The following query:

```
<?php

$criteria = new Criteria();
$criteria->clearSelectColumns();
$criteria->addSelectColumn(TableName::COLUMN1)
    ->addSelectColumn(TableName::COLUMN2)
    ->addAsColumn('alias1', 'DATE('.TableName::INIT_TIME.')')
    ->addAsColumn('alias2', 'COUNT('.TableName::DOWNLOAD_START_TIME.')')
    ->addGroupByColumn('DATE('.TableName::INIT_TIME.')')
    ->addGroupByColumn(TableName::DOWNLOAD_START_TIME);

$logs = TableName::doSelect($criteria);
```

Can be rewritten as below:

```
$query = TableNameQuery::create()
    ->select(array('Column1', 'Column2'))
    ->withColumn('DATE(InitTime)', 'alias1')
    ->withColumn('COUNT(DownloadStartTime)', 'alias2')
    ->groupBy('alias1')
    ->groupByDownloadStartTime()
    ;
$logs = $query->find();
```

Note you won't select both columns `alias1` and `alias2` as you didn't add them to the *selected columns* in your code. You can do that by adding the two alias to the `select()` clause:

```
    ->select(array('Column1', 'Column2', 'alias1', 'alias2'))
```

Answer (score 1):

I used this snippet to retrieve and fetch data when I followed this same approach, but selecting only one column in my `criteria` through `addSelectColumn`:

```
$logs = TableName::doSelectStmt($criteria); 
$data = $logs->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN, 0);
```

I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

My method is to make a query and iterate through a recordset. As suggested I use FETCH_BOTH to get array positions, but names as well. I take those values and hydrate my object, but also manually populate the properties of the object that are meant to hold the aggregate values. I pass those objects back to my application and use them as normal objects would be used in my view.

```
        $stmt = self::doSelectStmt($c);

        // empty array for now
        $results = array();
        // lets iterate through this
        while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_BOTH)) {
           // we need to create a new object
           $division = new Division();
           // and we'll hydrate each row turning into an object so we can use it easily
           $division->hydrate($row);
           // now here's the magic, this object did not exist from our tables, we'll fix that
           $division->setNumPlayers($row['num_players']);
           $division->setNumTeams($row['teams']);
           // set the output object
           $results[] = $division;
           } 
return $results; // array of objects including aggregate values
```